# How i could reset and clean the terminal in linux ubuntu using a command line?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

IN the terminal I put multiple variable like i=5 ; mn=hello; etc
and I need to reset this variable and all change that could exist in the teminal after start a command

How I could do this Please help me

I use command "reset" but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

```
   unset var
```

and this solve my problem